# Книги по ООП PHP

Tags: php, ооп, книги

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хорошие, качественные книги по ООП PHP с практическими примерами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Одна из самых лучших книг по ООП - [PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4574420/)

Answer (score 4):

[Head First Design Patterns](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6108824/), правда Java, но объектные модели и синтаксис с Java у php очень похож, так что понятно всё будет, а книга сама по себе замечательная и всё понятно.

насчёт  **PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования**, если покупать, то уже есть третье издание.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP и jQuery для профессионалов,** автор Джейсон Ленгсторф, есть в отличном качестве, в PDF, в Интернете...

Answer (score 1):

Вот посмотрите. В этой статье показаны примеры по объектно-ориентированному программированию:

http://ru.wh-db.com/article/chto-takoe-objecno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie/