# С чего начать изучение php?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток всем.
Хочу писать для себя очень простые скрипты.
К примеру, форум (очень очень простой) - просто тупо размещение сообщений. Систему личных сообщений там не знаю, еще что-нибудь.
чтобы душа радовалась, и я реально смог бы делать мини движок такой для сайта.
Знаю, что тяжело и долго. - поэтому на сложный профессиональный движок не рассчитываю.

Что почитать? Где поискать готовые варианты? (по отдельности). С самым простым кодом, а не мега сложным, где даже система отправления сообщений ужасно сложная с bbкодами и т.д, что я еще не знаю.

Comment: читайте книги про пхп) + форумы сами знаете про что) 

Comment: Опыт программирования на других языках есть? Хотя, раз возник такой вопрос - значит нет. Начни с какого-нибудь учебника алгебры логики. А писать на любом языке высокого уровня просто - на человеческом языке говоришь что машине делать - и она делает.

Comment: а какую-нибудь посвежей книжку по практическим примерам (типа как в Кузнецов, Симдянов)есть?
просто все какой-то далекий 2005 год попадается.

Comment: А какая разница, с чего начинать? Циклы, ветвления и типы переменных во всех версиях одинаковы. Не торопись лезть в ООП - и будет тебе счастье...)

Comment: Евгений Попов "Php в Видеоформате" Мне  помогло это!

Comment: да хрен там. ничего нет по Попову этому. html, css видел курс.

Comment: Есть и по PHP, но там как он говорил 80% языка опишет, с истиной не сходится, хотя в принцип может и кому-то помогает

Comment: Не знаю, по php не увидел. Только один урок какой-то. Введение по моему.

Comment: @qiwi, не увидели, и хорошо, повезло вам.

Comment: я только процедурный php знаю, и мне этого хватает)
Учил по видеокурсам Е. Попова)

Comment: denwer + кукбук за 24 часа

Comment: незнаю что вам не нравится мне помогло на 70% и ещё сайт php.su и это сайт тоже!

Comment: Наоборот, не надо ставить Denwer, научитесь конфигурироват ьсервер сами, а потом уже используйте пакеты. Это как писать на jQuery, не зная JavaScript.

Comment: Найдите книгу. Желательность с видеоуроками. Если будут проблемы, спрашивайте совета здесь или на форуме

Comment: Всегда нужно стремиться к большему...

Comment: четко ))))

Comment: Попов и программирование абсолютно никак не связанные вещи

Answer (score 6):

Google в помощь. А вообще советую книгу PHP. Практика создания WEB сайтов Максима Кузнецова, Игоря Симдянова - там описывается создание простого движка CMS, разработка форума и прочие прибамбасы для сайта. У них есть также книга PHP 5/6 можете изучать с нее или использовать эти книги вместе. Практика и еще раз практика. Удачи Вам.

Answer (score 5):

Для начала изучить [html](http://htmlbook.ru/), почитать и представлять что такое CSS.

Затем  "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и Javascript" издательства O'Reilly - хорошая книга по этим трем технологиям. Кстати, в ней в примерах поэтапно создается простенькая соц. сеть

Answer (score 3):

Например, вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135291/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF-php) спрашивали про "Книги по ООП PHP"

Answer (score 3):

Советую Вам посмотреть [курс PHP от Специалист](http://nnm-club.ru/?q=%D1%EF%E5%F6%E8%E0%EB%E8%F1%F2+php&w=title), мне очень понравился. Преподаватель очень доходчиво объясняет.. Вообщем не потратите свое время зря 100%. Советую.

Comment: Да, обязательно посмотрю этот курс.
Сейчас смотрю уроки на php Евгения Харина.

Answer (score 1):

Изучать php следует начать с изучения python. После него Вам вряд-ли захочется тратить время на php, ибо Вам будет казаться, что Вы пересаживаетесь с Бентли на Жигули.

Comment: Ребят, не холивара ради, Я сам прошел через этот путь.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю @nolka и плюсую, я (на свою беду купил учебник по PHP в книжном магазине потратив 90000сум) когда начал читать про PHP узнал что в нём всё очень не организовано (ф-ции называются по разному [даже иногда в разном стиле для работы с одним и темже типом обьектов] ) очень не стабилен (бывают моменты в которых сказано "компилятор/транслятор ведёт себя не стабильно в таких ситуациях") поттвердил это своим опытом а также узнал о том что PHP очень ресурсоёмок для сервера. Вывод: PHP - фуфло,деньги зря порачены,ищю книги про Perl. ИМХО

Comment: UPD: Единственные плюсы PHP - лёгкое обращение к пришедшим POST и GET методом файлам и данным, библиотека для работы с графикой.С перл пока так подробно не сталкивался но мне кажется что он спасобен на это тоже (и даже на большее) ИМХО

Comment: Ну зачем же так кидаться словами? :) Последние версиии пшп довольно шустро работают. Пшп не фуфло, после после питона он кажется каким-то унылым, и очень неудобным - много лишнего писать приходится.

Answer (score 1):

Книги прошлый век! В книге ответ на вопрос "как просканировать каталог на наличие png файлов" будет занимать очень много времени, в то время как google выдаст нужный ответ.

1. Вы должны понять концепцию php
2. Пользоваться google ищя нужные функции.

Имея эти 2 вещи знания php будут постоянно укрепляться и рости.

Удачи!